# how to convert numbers to strings with loops only?

Tags: java, loops

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=input.nextLine();
int a=s.length();
String v;
int[] arrayno={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
char b;
String[] array={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{    
    b=s.charAt(i);
    if(b==arrayno[i])
    {
        v=array[i];
        System.out.println(v);
    }
    else   
        System.out.print(b);
}
```

**Example:**

Input:

```
I have 3 Networking books, 0 Database books, and 8 Programming books.
```

Output:

```
I have three Networking books, zero Database books, and eight Programming books.
```

using loops only!

But this prints the same phrase entered! 
What can i do?

Comment: StackOverflow is a question-answering service, not a code-writing service. Write your own code and ask questions.

Comment: Programming isn't just about Input & Output :0

Comment: Your variable `i` points to an index within `s`, but you're then using `arrayno[i]`, which isn't relevant. You need a second loop to iterate through the items within `arrayno`, i.e. `for(int i=0;i<a;i++) { for(int j=0;j<arrayno.length();j++) {... if b==arrayno[j] ...}}`

Comment: That's not helping .. i wanna to print the name of the number i wrote in the program when i enter it ! .. like the Example

Answer (score 0):

The below code works only for your scenario i.e, numbers from 0-10.
But I feel this is not the correct way to work with numbers.

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();

String[] numbers={"10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0"};
String[] numberInWords={"ten", "nine", "eight", "seven",
     "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "one", "zero"};

for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {

    if(input.contains(numbers[i])) {
        input = input.replaceAll(numbers[i], numberInWords[i]);             
    }
}  

System.out.println(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that using a HashMap (in java.util) would be most appropriate here instead of two arrays. Your question asks for a solution using loops only, but it is unclear what classes are fair game and what are not.

My solution looks like this:

```
HashMap numberMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

numberMap.put("0","zero");
numberMap.put("1","one");
numberMap.put("2","two");
numberMap.put("3","three");
numberMap.put("4","four");
numberMap.put("5","five");
numberMap.put("6","six");
numberMap.put("7","seven");
numberMap.put("8","eight");
numberMap.put("9","nine");
numberMap.put("10","ten");

System.out.println("Enter something:");
String input = scan.nextLine();
String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
String output = "";

for (int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
    if (numberMap.containsKey(inputArray[i])){
        output += numberMap.get(inputArray[i]);
    } else {
        output += inputArray[i];
    }
    output += " ";
}

System.out.println(output);
```